# How to perform a command only if there is a change in a subdirectory with git?

Tags: git, bash

I want to run a command lazily on my CI server if and only if there is a change in a subdirectory (between the two latest commits), preferably using git diff.

Comment: So you have a local git repo and want to check if there are any changes in you code (staged or/and unstaged) ? And if so you want to execute a command ? Please explain the details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some kind of a file system watcher (like, for example [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)) to do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, clarified the question now. It is in a offline scenario where the CI runs a build, and I want to skip some commands if no files have changed in a sub-folder

Comment: There is also a deamon variant - `incrond`/`icrond`. I used to do `inotifywait | while read ...` loop. but i(n)crond can do it much easily.

Answer (score 0):

`[[ -z "$(git diff --numstat your-sub-folder)" ]] || echo "Changes"`

Will run git diff in a subshell, comparing content in "your-sub-folder", and echo Changes if there are any changes detected.